# Fluent UI React - how to apply global component styles with Fluent ThemeProvider

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm working with the theming code below.  I'm able to apply a global Fluent theme with the ThemeProvider and createTheme utility, but when I add component specific themes, I'm not getting any typings, which makes theming very difficult.

So **my question is**: how do I apply global component-specific styles using Fluent ThemeProvider with strong typing.

If, for example, I wanted to add a box shadow to all Fluent PrimaryButtons, I wouldn't know what properties to access on the `components` key passed into `createTheme`.

If you've done any global component theming, please let me know what pattern you used and if I'm on the right track, thanks!

```js
import { createTheme } from '@fluentui/react';
import { PartialTheme } from '@fluentui/react-theme-provider';

// Trying to add global component styles (not getting typings)
const customComponentStyles = {
    PrimaryButton: {
        styles: {
            root: {
                background: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
};

export const fluentLightTheme: PartialTheme = createTheme({
    components: customComponentStyles, // Want to apply component styles
    palette: {
        themePrimary: '#0078d4',
        themeLighterAlt: '#eff6fc',
        themeLighter: '#deecf9',
        themeLight: '#c7e0f4',
        themeTertiary: '#71afe5',
        themeSecondary: '#2b88d8',
        themeDarkAlt: '#106ebe',
        themeDark: '#005a9e',
        themeDarker: '#004578',
        neutralLighterAlt: '#faf9f8',
        neutralLighter: '#f3f2f1',
        neutralLight: '#edebe9',
        neutralQuaternaryAlt: '#e1dfdd',
        neutralQuaternary: '#d0d0d0',
        neutralTertiaryAlt: '#c8c6c4',
        neutralTertiary: '#a19f9d',
        neutralSecondary: '#605e5c',
        neutralPrimaryAlt: '#3b3a39',
        neutralPrimary: '#323130',
        neutralDark: '#201f1e',
        black: '#000000',
        white: '#ffffff'
    }
});
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? Can you share your solution or what you ended up doing instead?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, that components is just a `Record<string, ComponentStyles>`, where `ComponentStyles` then just is a quite unspecific object of the form `{ styles?: IStyleFunctionOrObject<any, any>}`. They would have to add an entry for every possible `I<Component>Styles` interface to `ComponentsStyles`, which I guess would be too much work and errorprone (e.g. forgetting to add a new component here ...).

Since all the `I<Component>Styles` interfaces are exported by Fluent, I always define the styles for each component separately and than merge them in the `components` object:

```js
const buttonStyles: IButtonStyles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
};

export const fluentLightTheme: PartialTheme = createTheme({
    components: { PrimaryButton: { styles: buttonStyles } },
});
```

Here is a codepen example I created by using one of Fluent UIs basic Button examples: https://codepen.io/alex3683/pen/WNjmdWo